# SpringBoot JPA Fetch/LoadGraph

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

I've two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCALIZATION")
@NamedQuery(name = "getByCountry,
    query = "SELECT ld FROM LocalizationDefinition ld WHERE ld.country = :country")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "loadAll",
    attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value = "localizations") })
public class LocalizationDefinition  {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "LocalizationSequence", sequenceName = "LOCALIZATION_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LocalizationSequence")
private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "localizationDefinition")
  private List<LocalizationEntry> localizations;
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCALIZATION_DETAIL")
public class LocalizationEntry  {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "LocalizationDetailSequence", sequenceName = "LOCALIZATION_DETAIL_SEQ",
        allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LocalizationDetailSequence")
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne 
  @JoinColumn(name = "LOCALIZATION_ID", nullable = false)
  private LocalizationDefinition localizationDefinition;
...
 }
```

Repository extract

```
    public List<LocalizationDefinition> getByCountry(final String country) {
      final TypedQuery<LocalizationDefinition> query = em
            .createNamedQuery("getByCountry", LocalizationDefinition.class);

      query.setParameter("country", country);
      query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", em.getEntityGraph("loadAll"));

      final List<LocalizationDefinition> allLocalizations = query.getResultList();

      return allLocalizations;
 }
```

I've a custom repository implementation which uses the named query and entity graph to load all entries for country. I'm using Spring Boot 1.4 with the embedded Tomcat and have tried EclipseLink 2.5.2 and 2.6.3. My expectation is, that only 1 SQL query is created but I end up with the n +1 query problem. I'm sure that this worked as expected in a JEE 7 test application in Weblogic Server 12c some month ago.

Any ideas, if I'm doing something wrong or missunderstand something?

Complete persistence.xml
First I'd a 2.0 version but updating it to 2.1 doesn't change anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="MatCommonEntity">
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
      <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database"
                  value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

eclipselink.weaving is set to static in the JPA config class. I've also enabled static weaving during compile time in my pom.xml.

Setting query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "ld.localizations"); in a custom repository implementations solves the problem. But this is provider specific and setting a loadgraph should already do the job.

Comment: How did you define that you get N+1?

Comment: Also, show your persistence.xml

Comment: persistence.xml

Comment: <persistence-unit name="MatCommonEntity">
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>        <properties>
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.target-database"                     value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform"/>
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>

Comment: Sorry, for the layout. It's hard to add something formated as comment. I've enabled the JPA/SQL logging in Spring-Boot and see the sql queries in the log. One solution I found, was to use a special eclipselink hint: query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "ld.localizations"); But this is provider specific and the loadgraph should already do the job.

Comment: You don't need to add this to comments, just update your question with new information. I don't see the root persistence tag - what version attribute is set there?